# Cannot click 'Install Respository...' in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to update my SDK versions in a project and am getting an error that I am specifying an 'incorrect' android:support library version. (I find this process very clumsy and it would be useful if AS would suggest the correct version which it does only sometimes).

Anyway, when I get the error during gradle sync it looks like the error contains clickable links to help resolve the issue, but clicking `Install Repository and sync project` does nothing. It seems not to be clickable - even though the other two options `Show in File` and `Show in Project Struvture dialog` work as expected.

[image]

There are a number of similar questions on SE, but none of the answers seem to work at all. Maybe its because AS has changed?

I'm running AS v2.3.3.

I have the following lines added to my project level `build.gradle` file to include the new maven repository:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
        }
    }
}
```

but still the `Install Repository...` link does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `url 'https://maven.google.com'` with `url "https://maven.google.com"`

> i.e use double quotes

AND

In the app level of the settings.gradle file add:

```
dependencies{
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'}
```

Comment: Upgrading to AS 3.0 seems to have sorted the problem and has automatically added the `maven` line - again with single quotes, not double.  And part of the problem seems to be finding what the correct version is for the support library...